# Terminal doesn't seem to be pulling through .profile automatically

Tags: macos, terminal

I've been adding some alias's and .bash_profile functions of late. But i've noticed my mac terminal is not auto-loading the .profile file and thus the alias's don't work.

I have restarted terminal and the mac itself.

I can get it to work by doing this, but it's a sucky work around:

```
. .profile
```

Anyone had this before / know how I can fix it up.

My .profile file contains the following:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced

alias testsite="cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/testsite/"
alias mamp="cd /Applications/MAMP/"
alias htdocs="cd /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/"
alias deploy="git push"
alias deploymaster="git push parent master"
alias pullmaster="git pulll parent master"
```

Comment: Do you have both `.bash_profile` and `.profile`? If the former is present, the latter won't be loaded.

Comment: indeed i do, guess thats the problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

.bash_profile overwrites .profile so what I added must be added to .bash_profile instead, when done so works perfectly.